# Different ways to publish media-enhanced route/trail information to mobile users

Tags: openstreetmap, kml, android, point-of-interest, tracking

I'm looking for some different approaches that a non-profit I'm helping could use to publish information about some tourism routes. Each route is 1-2 tracks, with some historical  background information in the form of text and pictures, plus some POIs representing specific historical details and logistics (eg, toilets, parking, cafes, hotels...) We'd like to be able to give this to people in a form they can use on mobile phones, while enjoying the trails - preferably available offline. Ideally, they would be able to see at a glance "20m on my left is a former rail station [see photo], and the nearest food is 3km further ahead up a steep hill". The view would (ideally) be linear, rather than just a top down 2D map view.

So, some approaches we've thought of so far:

- Develop an app for each route
- Find an app that does most of what we want, and provide content for it (everytrail.com is one example - would like to hear of others)
- Provide track and POI information in KMZ form, choose a recommended app or two (eg, Locus), and give instructions on how to combine them.

We're also adding information to OpenStreetMap where appropriate.

So - I would love to hear of any other possible ways to tackle this. We may well pursue more than one simultaneously.

[Apologies if this isn't quite within the scope of GIS. It's not quite within the scope of SO, SU or Android either...]

Comment: "Apologies if this isn't quite within the scope of GIS" it is well within the scope of GIS - osm,kml,tracking is huge business in todays world. My question is there any specific mobile device/os or to be any generic smart phones/tablets?

Comment: TripAdvisor has something similar - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tripadvisor.android.apps.cityguide.london#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLnRyaXBhZHZpc29yLmFuZHJvaWQuYXBwcy5jaXR5Z3VpZGUubG9uZG9uIl0.

Comment: I guess we're primarily targeting phones and not tablets out of practicality - you can't easily use a tablet while cycling. Android and iPhone seem to have similar uptake, so they're both important - the others less so.

Comment: Thanks Mapperz - that also leads me to other similar apps from developers "GPS city guide", "tourias" and "GuidePal city guides". They all look like closed systems though - no opportunity for us to contribute our own content.

Comment: Will your osm/routing data be offline? or connected to a database/map api to generate on the fly routing etc?

Comment: We'd really prefer to provide data that can be used entirely offline: a track, photos, text etc.

Answer (score 1):

For Android OSM has quite a few Apps (some Free, some are not)

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android

I have been using SportsTracker for years (originally on Nokia N82) Android now.

for Apple (iOS)

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS

OpenMaps is quite good.

These are only starting points...

Comment: I like the link! The ArcGIS iOS is out of date.  The latest version adds editor tracking, and CSV support +.

Comment: drop the releases/view/64859 and point to http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/ gets you to version 2.0

Comment: Yeah, there's no shortage of general purpose fitness or mapping apps that show a map and GPS location. I'm looking for a way we can publish a "tour": a track with photos and text that correspond to specific places. Maybe some of the apps under "monitoring features" can do this kind of thing.